# When was the last commercial hot air balloon fatality in the UK?

Tags: accidents, uk, accident-statistics, balloon

When was the last commercial hot air balloon fatality in the UK?

Comment: How are we defining "Commercial" here? Pilot in command is holder of a commercial license? Flight was with paying passengers? Some CAA/EASA/AAIB definition to do with the nature of the flight? I've made my best guess as to your intent in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All fatal accidents in the UK that occur with aircraft are investigated by the [Air accidents Investigation Branch (AAIB)](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/air-accidents-investigation-branch), and their database is [searchable](https://www.gov.uk/aaib-reports?aircraft_category%5B%5D=sport-aviation-and-balloons&keywords=balloon). Their records go back as far as 1915 (although it is not certain that all have been digitalised).

Given the digital records which are available on their website, there have been no investigated reports listing fatalities involving a hot air balloon with the type of  flight identified as "Commercial Air Transport (Passenger)"

Comment: So this makes it the safest form of aviation in the UK, if you're a paying passenger that is

Comment: @Cloud I wouldnt jump to that conclusion - safety is a factor of passenger hours not absolute numbers.